# Newton's Method Convergence Rate when first derivative is non-zero and second derivative is zero

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

Using the Taylor expansion it is easy to show that the convergence of Newton's method for a root $\alpha$ is quadratic when $f'(\alpha)\neq0$ and $f''(\alpha)\neq0$. If instead $f'(\alpha)=0$ and $f''(\alpha)\neq0$ we have linear convergence.

What is the case however if $f'(\alpha)\neq0$ and $f''(\alpha)=0$?

I have found using Taylor's Theorem that the limit of
$\Big\lvert\frac{x_{k+1}-\alpha}{x_k-\alpha}\Big\rvert
$
is $0$ using $f(x_k)=f'(\alpha)(x_k-\alpha)+\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_k)(x_k-\alpha)^2$ which fails to conclude linear convergence. Surely we need more information about the value of $f'''(\alpha)$ to deduce more about the convergence of the method? Is it possible that the method does not converge in this case?

Any hints would be great!

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in your remark about linear convergence: if $f'(\alpha)=0$, then Newton's method will blow up.

Comment: @innerproduct In that case we can Taylor expand as $$f(x_k)=\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_k)(x_k-\alpha)^2$$ with $\xi_k$ between $x_k$ & $\alpha$. This gives $$x_{k+1}-\alpha=x_k-\alpha-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}=(x_k-\alpha)\Big(1-\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x_k-\alpha)f''(\xi_k)}{f'(x_k)}\Big)$$ The limit of $f''(\xi_k)$ is $f''(\alpha)\neq 0$ and we can use $\frac{0}{0}$ L'Hopital to show the limit of the fraction is $\frac{1}{f''(\alpha)}$. All of this gives $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\Big\rvert\frac{x_{k+1}-\alpha}{x_k-\alpha}\Big\rvert=\frac{1}{2}$$ showing linear convergence. Is there a mistake here?

Comment: No, I agree. You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of any assumptions, the first step of the local analysis of Newton's method for $f$ at least $C^2$ goes like

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f'(\alpha) r_n + f''(\alpha) r_n^2/2 + o(r_n^2)}{f'(\alpha)+f''(\alpha) r_n+o(r_n)}$$

since $f(\alpha)=0$, so this gives the two Taylor expansions. When $f'(\alpha) \neq 0$, regardless of anything else, you can then write

$$x_{n+1}=x_n - r_n \frac{1+\frac{f''(\alpha)}{2f'(\alpha)} r_n+o(r_n)}{1+\frac{f''(\alpha)}{f'(\alpha)} r_n + o(r_n)}.$$

Then you can further write

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-r_n \left ( 1+\frac{f''(\alpha)}{2f'(\alpha)} r_n + o(r_n) \right ) \left ( 1-\frac{f''(\alpha)}{f'(\alpha)} r_n + o(r_n) \right ) \\
= x_n - r_n \left ( 1-\frac{f''(\alpha)}{2f'(\alpha)} r_n + o(r_n) \right ) \\
= \alpha + \frac{f''(\alpha)}{2f'(\alpha)} r_n^2 + o(r_n^2).$$

You can still do this "further" computation if $f''(\alpha)=0$. It is just that then the result reads

$$x_{n+1}=\alpha + o(r_n^2)$$

which is not completely telling you the behavior of the error. Instead it is only telling you that the error behaves as $o(r_n^2)$ (i.e. faster than quadratic convergence).